# Does the series $ \sum_k^\infty \frac{k!}{k^k}$ converge to an irrational number and does it have any significance or applications?

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

I know that the series

$$ \sum_k^\infty \frac{k!}{k^k} $$

converges by the ratio test.

The sum calculated by wolfram alpha is $~1.87985386217525853348630614507096$ which seems pretty irrational to me.

But is it in any way significant? It there a proof that it is an irrational number? Are there any applications of this series?

---

I completely forgot about the Stirling's approximation for the factorial.

Since for $k  \rightarrow +\infty$ the factorial approaches

$$
k! \sim  \sqrt{2 \pi k} \frac{k^k}{e^k}
$$

So it seems obvious that the series give irrational number.

Comment: Try working with $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{k}\right)$$

Comment: The argument using an approximation of the factorial is irrelevant. Like saying that $\pi$ is an integer because $3$ approximates it.

Comment: See [Sloane's](http://oeis.org/A094082).  The irrationality seems to be an open question.  But it's surely irrational, and transcendental, based on the heuristic that "there's no good reason for it to be rational or algebraic."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be relevant to notice that:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k!}{k^k}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x^k}{k^k}e^{-x}\,dx&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k-1} \frac{x^k}{(k-1)!} e^{-x}\int_{0}^{1}(y\log y)^{k-1}\,dy\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{1}xe^{-x}\cdot y^{-xy}\,dy\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{(1+y\log(y))^2}\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{e^{z}\left(1-z e^{-z}\right)^2}.\end{eqnarray*}$$
Now the classical approach for showing that some constant is an irrational number is to provide some accurate rational approximation, too accurate to be approximations for a rational number.  The last integral is not the most manageable I have met in my life, but [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) may provide a good way to go.

On the other hand, only the order of growth of the coefficients of a series converging to $\alpha$ tells us *nothing* about the rationality or irrationality of $\alpha$. Consider, for instance:

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^3}=\zeta(3)\not\in\mathbb{Q},\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{F_n}{19^n}=\frac{19}{341}\in\mathbb{Q}.$$